# GAE cron request limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-directory-api, google-email-settings-api

I'm currently developing an GAE cron application which calls the directory API to fetch some user data and then updates the user email signature using that data.

My problem is the 10 min limit of a cron job. From an approximate calculus, the flow will last about one and half hours which is more that the 10 mins cron offers.

Is there any way I can overcome that limit? Can i somehow start a thread that will asynchronously do the processing I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can divide the code into `Module`, set up Manual Scaling and you can run tasks for up to 24 hours
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

Comment: You can use Modules within free quota. Just be careful quota is assigned to each applications, not each modules. So for example if you make 2 modules in an application, you need to share 28 hours instance quota in 2 modules, if you make 2 applications instead, you have 28 hours instance quota for each apps (total 56 hours).

Comment: I just need one module in which i do my processing. Where did you find the free plan or quota? From what I'm seeing in the docs there isn't such thing...

Comment: I found it in the meantime. It's: 28 instance-hours for automatic scaling, 8 instance-hours for manual and 8 instance-hours for basic.